# How can i find the first n negative integers by using an array

Tags: python, arrays, sys

I wanted to find a way i can the first n negative integers so if i put in 7 it would produce `[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7]`

```
import stdio
import sys

n = int(input(sys.argv[0]))

arr= list(range(-1,n))

print(arr)
```

Comment: Use a [heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) - `heapq.nsmallest(n, iterable, key=None)`

Comment: `arr= list(range(-1, -n - 1, -1))`

Answer (score 4):

In Python, [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) defaults to counting up by 1. You can change this by providing a negative value for *step*, which is the third argument to `range()`. You will also need to provide the correct *stop* value, which in your case is `-n-1`.

```
import stdio
import sys

n = int(input(sys.argv[0]))

arr = list(range(-1,-n-1,-1))

print(arr)

[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a "List Comprehension"

```
import stdio
import sys

n = int(input(sys.argv[0]+'\nPick a number, any number\n'))

arr= [-i for i in range(1,n+1)]

print(arr)
```